# Pyspark set a new column based on another column for a group

Tags: pyspark

So I have a pyspark dataframe which looks like the following:

```
id item price
1  x    2.0
1  y
2  z    1.0
```

And wanna turn it into the following:

```
id item price max_price
1  x    2.0   2.0
1  y          2.0
2  z    1.0   1.0
```

so basically find max price where grouped by id. I tried the following:

```
df = df.withColumn('price', max('price').over(Window.partitionBy('id')))
```

which won't work as the column type is string and I can not convert it. Is there a way to somehow covert that value on fly? or a function that could get me any non-empty price per groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just cast the `price` to `decimal` type in **`max`** window function

**`Example:`**

```
df = df.withColumn('price', max(col('price').cast("decimal(10,2)").over(Window.partitionBy('id')))
```

---

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1','x','2.0'),('1','y',''),('2','z','1.0')],['id','item','price'])
df.withColumn("price", max(col("price").cast("decimal(10,2)")).over(Window.partitionBy('id'))).show(10,False)
#+---+----+-----+
#|id |item|price|
#+---+----+-----+
#|1  |y   |2.00 |
#|1  |x   |2.00 |
#|2  |z   |1.00 |
#+---+----+-----+
```